# 1 << 31 cannot be represented by type 'int'?

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, sanitizer

Why does `-fsanitize=undefined` throw

> runtime error: left shift of 1 by 31 places cannot be represented in type 'int'

on this code

```
uint32_t z;
z = 1 << 31;
```

?

Comment: Shifting into (or beyond) the sign bit is undefined behavior.  While `z` is `uint32_t`, `1` is a plain old `int`, which is signed (and not necessarily 32 bits wide).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the 1 unsigned:

```
uint32_t z;
z = UINT32_C(1) << 31;
```

Comment: That's not guaranteed to work. `1u` is of type `unsigned int`, which is not guaranteed to be wider than 16 bits. You say you need to cast it, but then you don't cast it. You can do `unsigned uint32_t z = (uint32_t)1 << 31;`

Comment: Better to use a constant literal of the correct type than cast: `UINT32_C(1) << 31`

Comment: @ChrisDodd What issues could casting present?

Comment: The cast will be constant-folded away so has no extra cost (except when optimization is completely disabled), but occasionally causes precedence confusion.  Using `static_cast<`.. can avoid the latter, but is C++ only and more verbose.  The constant literal ensures that it is really constant.

Answer (score 5):

Because a left shift of 1 by 31 places cannot be represented in type `int`.

Mathematically, `1 << 31` is 2<sup>31</sup>, or `2147483648`. `INT_MAX` on a typical system (where `int` is 32 bits) is one less than that, or `2147483647`. If an arithmetic operation on a signed type overflows (yields a result outside the result of the type), the behavior is undefined. (Don't assume it will wrap around. It might, but the language doesn't guarantee it.)

If you need a type that can represent that value, you can use an unsigned type that's at least 32 bits wide, or a signed type that's more than 32 bits wide.  `unsigned long` or `long long` is guaranteed to be that wide. (The language doesn't guarantee that `int` is more than 16 bits wide, but it's likely to be 32 on most systems.)